# Reverse not found, Django, first time

Tags: python, django

`search.html` is the page where shows search results list, but when I click on "Search" button it shows me an error page "Reverse not found".. I saw same questions here, but the codes are different, so I didn't find the solution of my problem.

```
def search(request):
if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
    q = request.GET['q']
    words = word.objects.filter(title__icontains = q)
    return render_to_response('dictionary/search.html',
        {'words': words, 'query': q })
else:
    return HttpResponse('Please submit a search term.')


def worder(request, word_id):
    showword = get_object_or_404(word, id = word_id)
    return render(request, 'dictionary/worder.html', {'showword': showword})
```

The urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', Dictionary.views.home, name='home'),
url(r'^about/$', Dictionary.views.about, name='about'),
url(r'^search/$', Dictionary.views.search, name='search'),
url(r'^worder/(?P<word_id>[0-9]+)/$', Dictionary.views.worder, name='worder')]
```

There is a problem with `{% url 'worder' word_id %}`:

```
<li class="listofwords"><a class="foundword" href="{% url 'worder' word_id %}">{{ word.title }}</a></li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a variable `word_id` that doesn't exist. You should use `word.id` which is the id of your object word instead:

```
<li class="listofwords"><a class="foundword" href="{% url 'worder' word.id %}">{{ word.title }}</a></li>
```

Comment: OMG!!! Thank you very much, Shang Wang! I've spent the whole day searching for solutions of the problem!